# A word or set of words for "tenancy in common" without real estate connotation?

Tags: phrase-requests, synonyms

Is there a word, combination of words or neologism that essentially brings to mind the idea that my new company is creating a contractual structure through which a group of people can collectively participate in the ownership of a good thing, which (without said structure) they otherwise would not have access to? Since this will be used in the context of corporate branding and marketing, the word(s) hopefully would be useful as either a company name or a product name, although I can play with this given right word(s).

Perhaps another word for "tenancy in common" or "condominium" but without the real estate connotations?

Comment: That is exactly what a [corporation](https://www.google.com/search?q=corporation+define&rlz=1C1FLDB_enUS535US535&oq=corporation+define&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.9688j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) is.

Comment: You can be members of a club. You can be a fractional owner. You can be a stockholder.

Answer (score 1):

You probably mention a ***co-operative (also known as co-op, cooperative or coop)*** composed of the members (employees or customers) of the company.

Something like:

> XYZ Company (Member) Coop for Blah Blah

From **[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative)**:

> **Cooperative**
>
> A co-operative (also known as co-op, cooperative or coop) is an autonomous association of people united voluntarily to
> meet their common economic, social and cultural needs and aspirations
> through a jointly owned and democratically controlled business.